# Matching table data to display results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, authentication

looking for help getting data from my tables.

So far I have 2 tables, one named: **userlogin** which contains log in information listed by 'user_id' my next table is called **userinfo** which at the moment just contains user name and address, again listed by 'user_id'

Currently I have a log in page, and a home page. The log in page uses the information from the  **userlogin** table to verify that the user has an account and they have entered the correct information.

Now this is were it gets tricky, (for me at least) as on this homepage i'm trying to display the information from the **userinfo** table which relates to the user_id from the **userlogin** table.

Here is my loginpage code

```
<?php
// Use session variable on this page. This function must put on the top of page.
session_start();
$_SESSION['userName'] = 'Root';


////// Login Section.
$Login=$_POST['Login'];
if($Login){ // If clicked on Login button.
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password']; // Encrypt password with md5() function.

// Connect database. 
//connect
        $con = mysql_connect("*****","*****","*****");
        if (!$con)
         {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        //datebase
        mysql_select_db("*****, $con);

// Check matching of username and password.
$result=mysql_query("select * from userlogin where username='$username' and password='$password'");
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!='0'){ // If match.
session_register("username"); // Craete session username.
header("location:home.php"); // Re-direct to main.php
exit;
}else{ // If not match.
$message="--- Incorrect Username or Password ---";
}

} // End Login authorize check.
?>
```

Here is the code for my homepage, which is were the information will be shown to the user, upon login.

```
    <?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userName']))
?>

<?php
// Connect database. 
//connect
        $con = mysql_connect("****","*****","******");
        if (!$con)
         {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        //datebase
        mysql_select_db("*****", $con);
//select
        $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT userinfo.user_id, userlogin.user_id 
                           FROM userinfo 
                           INNER JOIN userlogin 
                           ON userinfo.user_id=userlogin=user_id");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

            { 

            echo $row['name'] . '</br>' ;
            echo $row['address'] . '</br>';

            }
```

?>

So far all i'm doing is displaying all the information from my **userinfo** table, and what I want is to limit this content to showing information that matches the user_id from the **userlogin** table to the user_id of the **userinfo** table and display the results.

[EDIT] I've edited my mysql in my homepage code, and now i'm displaying no results, and i'm still unsure how to make this work.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Also pls stop using mysql... And use PDO or MSQLI instead.

Comment: Man, you need to study inner join to join the table data

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userinfo.name as name, userinfo.address as address, userlogin.username as username  FROM userinfo, userlogin WHERE id = 1");
```

As an example.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['username'];
    echo $row['address'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I'm still unsure how to display the data, i've edited my code in my original post

Comment: Edited my post, just use it as you where using it before

Comment: I'm sorry, but still no luck, my homepage is just showing nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

you can JOIN these two tables on user_id, to get information from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the PHP PDO class for this.

https://www.php.net/pdo

As you're using the GET attribute, it could be easy for sql injection to occur if you don't use a prepared statement.

Take a look at [How can I properly use a PDO object for a parameterized SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767026/how-can-i-properly-use-a-pdo-object-for-a-select-query)

Use this as a guide, but use your ID column instead of name.