# How do I get value of <select> when a user select a item

Tags: php, html

I need help.

I have a select box with items and I want, if the user select a car name and click on "search" I need to have the name of the car he selected on a "echo".

I tried couple of things but it displays nothing (blank page).
below is my code.

Thanks in advance !

```html
<select name="category" >
    <option value="nocategory">No Category</option>
    <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
    <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
    <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
 </select>

<input name="submit"  value="Search" type="submit">

</form> 


<?php

   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $category = $_POST['category'];

?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get values from HTML select to php\sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24792927/how-to-get-values-from-html-select-to-php-sql)

Comment: SHow us your `<form>` tag

Comment: blank page, because you are not closing your if statement brackets;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set form action to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`   like below: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is a `PHP` `super global variable` which returns the `filename` of the currently executing script.

```
   <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="category" >
        <option value="nocategory">No Category</option>
        <option value="toyota">Toyota</option>
        <option value="nissan">Nissan</option>
        <option value="mazda">Mazda</option>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     </select>

    <input name="submit"  value="Search" type="submit">

   </form> 


    <?php

       if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $category = $_POST['category'];
       echo $category;
       }

    ?>
```