# How i can recive date from table using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i am newbie using this pdo to have access to the database. I am trying to get the ID from the database but I don't receive any data.

```
1:
$date = array(
            ':user' => $_POST['user'],
            ':pass' => $_POST['pass'],
    );
$user->login($date);

2
function login ($date) {
    $this->dbh->query("Select id From users Where username = ':user' and password = ':pass'");
    $result = $this->dbh->execute_array($date);
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $result['id'];
    //header("Location: game.php");
}

3
function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
}

function execute_array ($array) {
    return $this->stmt->execute($array);
}
```

edit:

i wrote the pdo code again making some changes that resolve my problem.

```
function login ($date) {
    $this->dbh->query("Select id From users Where username = :user and password = :pass");
    $this->dbh->execute_array($date);
    $result = $this->dbh->single();
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $result['id'];
    //header("Location: game.php");
}

function execute_array ($array) {
    $this->stmt->execute($array);
}

function single() {
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

ty for helping me with this.

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what is happening now? Do you receive any error messages on-screen or in your logs?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767026/how-can-i-properly-use-a-pdo-object-for-a-select-query

Comment: You're not actually fetching the results.

Comment: i dont recive any error..the code runing like the way i want but i dont recive any data..i have this code write with mysql but i'm changing to PDO so i dont know what's is happen..and i think that maybe i have some code missing.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to contain the answer, you should mark the answer below that you found to be correct or that solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You've got sql syntax errors:

```
[..snip..] username = ':user' and password = ':pass'
                      ^-----^----------------^-----^---here
```

placeholders do not ever need to be quoted. The database takes care of all that.

Plus, your `execute_array()` method is probably returning a statement HANDLE. That is not the actual results of your query, merely something you can use to get at those results.

You probably want something more like

```
   $result = $this->dbh->execute_array(...);
   $row = $result->fetch();
   $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object

Comment: i have this code to get single record's:

function single() {
  $this->execute();
  return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);}

i have to use something like this but the execute method will be with array?

Comment: whoops, sorry. it's just fetch(), and the error means that the query failed and returned a boolean false anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You prefer it this way:

```
try{
    $this->db= new PDO(DBHost, DBName, DBUser, DBPassword, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
    $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $this->db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

    $sql="Select id From users Where username = :user and password = :pass";

    $this->stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql, array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL));
    $this->stmt-> bindParam(':user', $date['user'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $this->stmt-> bindParam(':pass', $date['pass'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $this->stmt->execute();

    if ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NAMED, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT)) {
        return $row['id'];
    }else{
        return NULL;
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
//TODO....
}
```