# PDO connection login

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Would you please help me sort this problem out. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. My connection to database working correct but I'm unable to login.

**login.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

$username= $_POST["username"];
$password= $_POST["password"];

include("/inc/connect.inc.php");

if(!isset($conn)){
 $conn = null;
 header('Location: index.php');
}

else{
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`='$username' AND `password`='$password'");
$query ->execute(array(':username' =>$username, ':password' =>$password)
   );


  if (   ($query->rowCount() == 0) && (   ($password == null) or ($username == null)  )  ){
          echo "<h3>Please enter your username and password</h3>"; 
          $conn = null;
          header("Refresh: 3;URL=index.php");
 }  
 else if  ($query->rowCount() == 1)   
 {
         $_SESSION['user_logged'] = $_POST['username'];
         unset($username);
         unset($password);
         echo "<h3>Your password is correct</h3>";
         $conn = null; 
         header("Refresh: 3;URL=interface.php");
   }

  else  {
          echo "<h3>The username / password combination entered is incorrect!</h3>";
          unset($username);
          unset($password);
          $conn = null;
          header("Refresh: 3;URL=index.php");
 }  
}


?>
```

Previously I didn't understand *stackoverflow* rules. I hope this time my question is more accurate. I have done lot of work to get to this point and only have a problem with login to my database now. My `$query = $conn->prepare` not finding anything. It's jumping to *The username / password combination entered is incorrect!* at any time. If I leave username or/and password empty or putting correct username and password always the same result.

Comment: Well, you don't `echo` anything, what do you expect?

Comment: it's not bname it's dbname. $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database.'charset=utf8',$username,$password);

Comment: I turned on error reporting `error_reporting(0);` and still nothing.

Comment: Changed `dbname` as well.

Comment: When leave username or password empty I'm getting error message "You need to enter a username and password". But when I'm putting anything into the userame and password (correct or incorrect) I'm getting blank screen. Any ideas?

Comment: Simple: You're mixing `mysql_` with PDO, besides the typo in your connection. This should be an "answer" because it addresses the real problem, but I can't post one, because this would mean you would ask me how to convert your other code for PDO and I won't do that. That's your job.

Comment: You are welcome to convert my code to PDO. I can understand that this code is mixed up but have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: No Robert; I will not convert your code to PDO, that isn't my/our job; it's yours. Plus, this would take a lot of time to do this. We are not paid for this. There's easily an hour's work here, if not more.

Comment: @MySQLRockstar *"Turn on error reporting `error_reporting(0);` and see what you get"* - As per http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php that means "Turn **off** all error reporting". More like `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` ;-)

Comment: First you accept mine then another. Obviously not addressing any of the issues. You can do whatever you want, but mine explained it fully. We're not code converters here. Even though I put in an answer, I voted to close as to why it's not working.

Comment: Look I'm new to this place and have no idea how it works yet. I thought more than one answers can be correct and accepted.

Comment: Yeah well it looks like the accepted answer you now took, doesn't even convert all of the functions and you're still trying to make your code work. I took the time to fetch good tutorial links and address the real problems and the use of an unsafe password function; something they never bothered addressing. If you use that MD5, you will eventually get hacked. Don't practice using old technology. Anyway, do what you want. From what I saw in comments under the answer below, doesn't fix your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the connection string there is a typo:

Take a look at the examples here http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Update:  You seem to be totally lost so I'll step by step the code and the reason for things not working. The code I write will be filled with echo and print statements.

1.) You need to check your database connection but you have no code to do this. The connection might be fine but PHP does not throw an error.

```
try
{
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=' . $database . 'charset=utf8', $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    if(is_object($conn) && $conn != false)
    { 
         echo "I'm connected. PDO is ready and willing";        
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Sorry something went  horribly wrong! Not connected to database";
    {


}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    throw new pdoDbException($e);         
    echo die('Error Message:'.$e->getMessage());
}
```

2.) It will look like your connection is not working because none of functions is calling a connection. The connection object created is outside of the functions scope.

```
function user_exists($username)
{ 
    global $conn; // bring the connection object into scope
    $username = sanitize($username);
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM users WHERE username = :username");
$query ->execute(array(
    ':username' =>$username
));
 $user = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 return $user. ' exists in database';
```

}

3.) there's lots of code but none of the functions looks like they are being called at runtime. Test for user exists and if database connection works at  runtime in the init.php file

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

$errors = array();
// call a function  to check if user exists.
echo user_exists('user_123');

?>
```

Comment: I did changed this and looked on the link but still cannot connect.

Comment: Ok. It seems like you was right. I have connection but my code is mixed up and other bit in _user.php_ don't work correctly. How should I check only for `function user_exists($username)`? When I get this I will move forward.

Comment: I'm getting this message now: _I'm connected. PDO is ready and willing _ but when filling correctly username and password then _I'm connected. PDO is ready and willing
The username / password combination entered is incorrect!_ message appearing. I did change a lot in code now and there is no mixed up in PDO and mysql now.

Comment: I changed the code slightly to look for a  returned false  string if the object was not created.  The  init.php file can be used in step 3.) to check for user_exists(). Some of the checks are redundant but good to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this because it is an answer that addresses the real issue as to why the OP's code isn't working.

Firstly, a typo in `bname` which should read as `dbname` in your connection.

Now, you are mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_` functions and PDO.

- **Those different APIs do not intermix with each other.**

In comments you said:

> *"You are welcome to convert my code to PDO. I can understand that this code is mixed up but have no idea how to fix it."*

- **I don't like coming off as or sounding like the "bad man" here, but that isn't our job to convert your `mysql_` code to PDO, it's yours. We don't convert code on Stack, we help out with problematic code.**

There are plenty of tutorials out there for you to learn and use.

Here are but a few, which you can further your research on Stack/Google:

- http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
- http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

There is also the manuals on PHP.net

- http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php

On Stack:

- [How can I properly use a PDO object for a parameterized SELECT query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767026/)

---

**Regarding MD5 for passwords:**

```
$password = md5($password);
```

MD5 is old and considered broken and no longer safe to use for password storage.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

---

> *"I'm getting blank screen. Any ideas?"*

**Regarding "a blank screen".**

This means you have syntax errors.

Doing `error_reporting(0);` means "Turn off all error reporting"

As per the manual on PHP.net

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

What you need to do is turn error reporting on, not off.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Answer (score 0):

1st step. Change

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;bname='.$database.'charset=utf8',$username,$password);
```

to

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$database.';charset=utf8',$username,$password);
```

2st. You use mysqli and pdo in one project. For what?

Comment: Good question. I should use PDO only for this project but found some help online with mysql. Tis is why I ended with a little mixup.

Comment: I did changed this and still the same.