# Fatal error: Call to undefined function prepare()

Tags: php

I am getting an error on the $db line. I have tried placing a '->" before the prepare but then I get a Parse Error Syntax Error.

```
//try to login  
$db = pdo-prepare($sql);  
$username = $db->bindValue($_POST['username']);  
$password = $db->bindValue($_POST['password']);  
$tablePrefix = "";  
$UserAndPassTable = $tablePrefix . "user";
```

Comment: You need to set your PDO connection into `$db` before you can call `prepare()` . Then it would be  `$db->prepare($sql)` I think  this post gives real good information on how to use PDO prepared statements. http://stackoverflow.com/a/767520/6208463

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your PDO connection into $db before call prepare()

```
$stmt=$db->prepare($sql);
```

In my example $db is my PDO connection

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname;charset=utf8', 'user', 'pass');
```